# return List<T> for Generic type T

Tags: java, generics

I happened to use `<T>` instead of `List<T>` in the following code, and it works.

EDIT(sorry for not compiling code):

```
private <T, DAO> T getList(Class<Dao> clazz, Function<Dao, T> op) {
    Jdbi jdbi = Jdbi.create("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
    Handle handle = jdbi.open();
    DAO dao = handle.attach(clazz);
    T result = op.apply(myDao); 
    return result;
}
List<Data> getDataList() {
    return getList(MyDao.class, MyDao::getDataList); //myDao.getDataList return List<Data>
}
```

I don't understand why `<T>` didn't error out. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: That code fails to compile for me in both Java 8 and Java 10.

Comment: Same, this doesn't compile for me on Java 1.8

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: If you're confused about why it's legal to have `<T>` in the method signature, see [Generic Methods (Java Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html).

Comment: sorry for the not compiling code, I have edit the sample code. And I guess List<T> is a subset of T, so that it works.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a confusing choice for generics.

I suggest that you do this instead:

```
private Dao dao;

private List<Data> getList() {
    return this.dao.getDataList(); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you must be having a cast to (T) as shown below in your actual code.

```
    private <T> T getList(Dao myDao)
    {
        T result = (T) myDao.getDataList(); // myDao.getDataList return List<Data>
        return result;
    }
```

If yes, the the code will compile fine. You are defining getList method as returning an object of type T. Java will allow you to cast something to 'T' although with a warning.

Since there is no constraint on T in method definition. It is equivalent to 'Object' i.e your method is similar to '`private Object getList(Dao myDao){...}`'

In which case the return value can be list or map or any subclass of Object.

Basically, you have not specified what 'T' stands for. If you said '`<T extends List>`' for example then return type must be a subclass of list.

Another way you could re-write the method, with some clarity about T:

```
private <T extends Object> T getList(Dao myDao)
{
    T result = (T) myDao.getDataList(); 
    // Warning Type safety: Unchecked cast from List<Data> to T
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Excuse me for asking, but what is return type of your method? Type `T`, or `List<T>`?
(BTW. I didn't down voted)

Comment: The return type is 'T', there is no constraint on T so it is equivalent to returning Object. Contrast this to 'public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {' where T is constrained, it extends comparable, also it should match the generic type of 'list' parameter.